# Cyclic Dependency in Formik Yup Schema

Tags: formik, yup

I have 5 fields field1...field5 in my formik form.I am using Yup for schema validation. Only one of field1, field2,field3 are mandatory at a given time. Field4 and Field5 have independent validations which do not have any dependency of other fields whatsoever. I have figured a way of writing

```
schema = Yup.object().shape({
  field1: Yup.string().when(['field2', 'field3'], {
     is: (field2, field3) => !field2 && !field3,
     then: Yup.string().required()
}),
  field2: Yup.string().when(['field1', 'field3'], {
     is: (field1, field3) => !field1 && !field3,
     then: Yup.string().required()
}),
  field3: Yup.string().when(['field1', 'field2'], {
     is: (field1, field2) => !field1 && !field2,
     then: Yup.string().required()
}),
   field4: Yup.string().max(30, "Maximum 30 characters are allowed").required("This is a mandatory field"),
   field5: Yup.string().max(30, "Maximum 30 characters are allowed").required("This is a mandatory field")
}
,[['field1', 'field2'], ['field1', 'field3'], ['field2','field3']]
)
```

Please observe field4 and field5 are not mentioned in the second last line since they are not dependent on other fields. I mentioned field1,field2,field3 on the second last line since without it, the schema throws a cyclic dependency issue.

**My Question is**: Is the placement of field4 and field5 correct in the below schema.